# Can I suppress git hook e.g. prepare-commit-msg via git command line argument?

Tags: git

In some situation I want to not have the .git hooks to fire when I am committing a change e.g. prepare-commit-msg

Is there a easy way to suppress them via command line (maybe similar to `--no-verify`)

Comment: You can setup a custom check in the hook script.

Comment: A bit more details is appreciated. Do you mean checking, maybe, some env variable?

Comment: Yes, I meant that exactly.

Answer (score 4):

The best I could do (and at least this does answer the question) is get the parent's command line and look for '-n' or '--no-verify' passed to it.

```
if ps -o args= $PPID | grep -E -q ' --no-verify| -n | -n$' ; then
  : # they skipped the commit-msg hook, so skip this hook too!
else
  : # do your hook code here
fi
```

I'm sure there's better code out there, I just could NOT find any examples!

Answer (score -1):

you can do this with an environment variable:

```sh
SKIP=prepare-commit-msg git commit
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is one possible method though not that convenient.

1.Define a pair of git config key and value.

```
git config my.hook true
```

2.Use the key and value in the hook.

```
if [ "$(git config --get my.hook)" == "true" ];then
    #do something
fi
```

3.When you want to bypass this hook, run `git config my.hook false` first.

Comment: If you’re going to run a command first instead of making an environment variable check, it might be more useful to make that command `chmod -x .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg`. This allows you to say `git -c my.hook=false commit` in a single line. One suggestion for the script’s check, though: use `git config --get --bool` so that you can use other forms, like `=1` or `=0`, when setting the configuration.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. `-c` is what I was trying to find to make it elegant.